# crontab: command not found in CentOS

Tags: centos, cron, centos5, terminal

I tried to setup a cron job in my new CentOS VPS server over SSH. I typed in the command

`crontab -e` and I got the following error message:-

`-bash: anacrontab: command not found`

Any idea how I can set up cron job in CentOS?

********* CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

Comment: Can you run `which crontab` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `crontab` is an alias of `anacrontab` that doesn't exist. You can run the 'real' command by preceding it with a backslash `\`:

```
\crontab -e
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that cron software is loaded? Do

```
yum list|grep cron
```

Do you see something like

```
anacron.x86_64                           2.3-45.el5.centos            installed 
crontabs.noarch                          1.10-8                       installed 
vixie-cron.x86_64                        4:4.1-77.el5_4.1             installed
```